# How to solve this error "getRange is not a function" in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a code as follows. When I run the deLete function here, I get this `TypeError: tab.getRange is not a function` error. At first I did not have a problem writing the code. But then when adding various functions to this, did he have a problem? Can you help me solve this?
[image]

Originally the variable was like this

```
 var [tabb,x4, start,x1, end,x2, side,x3, item] = sheet.getRange("C5:C13").getValues().flat();
  var [tesNo,y1, rfiNo] = sheet.getRange("G15:G17").getValues().flat();
```

After the error came, I tried to change it as follows

```
const tab =spreadsheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange("C5").getValue());
```

This is the function that receives the error

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry Form');
  var regiWs = ss.getSheetByName('Data Registry');
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const tab =spreadsheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange("C5").getValue());

        function get_rows(tab, side, item) {
      try{
        Logger.log("test "+tab);
        // var tab = ss.getSheetByName(c5);//copy
      var items = tab.getRange("C:C").getValues().flat();
      if (side == 'LHS') return [items.indexOf(item) + 1];
      if (side == 'RHS') return [items.lastIndexOf(item) + 1];
      if (side == "BOTH SIDE") return [items.indexOf(item) + 1, items.lastIndexOf(item) + 1];
      //return []; // just in case, to avoud any errors due trash input data
      }catch(err){
        Logger.log("ERROR-get_rows "+ err)
      }
    }
    
    //find location & clor the bar
    function colorize_rows(tab, rows, start, end) {
      //var tab = ss.getSheetByName(c5); //copy
      var chainage_row = tab.getRange('c:c').getValues().flat().indexOf('Chainage') + 1;
      var chainage = tab.getRange(chainage_row, 4, 1, tab.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
      var start_index = chainage.findIndex(x => x > start);
      var end_index = chainage.findIndex(x => x >= end) - start_index;
    
      var tesNo= sheet.getRange("G15").getValue();
      var rfiNo= sheet.getRange("G17").getValue();
      var comment =tesNo+" => "+rfiNo;
    
      for (row of rows) {
        var color = tab.getRange('c' + row).getBackground();
            if(tab.getRange(row, start_index+3, 1, end_index+1).isPartOfMerge() == true){
              SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Can't mark the vlaues in bar chart. Part length  or full length of it has overlapped. Please check it.");
              Logger.log("Can't mark the bar chart, it's part length  or full length overlapped")
              //to be run delete last record
    
    
    }else{
      tab.getRange(row, start_index+3, 1, end_index+1)
        .setBackground(color)
        .mergeAcross()
        .setValue(comment)    
        .setHorizontalAlignment("center")
        .setVerticalAlignment("center")
        .setBorder(null, true, null, true, false, false);
        }
      }   
    }
    
    
    //use for edit & delete
    function unMerge(tab, rows, start, end) {
      
      Logger.log("trst "+tab);
      var chainage_row = tab.getRange("C:C").getValues().flat().indexOf('Chainage') + 1;
      var chainage = tab.getRange(chainage_row, 4, 1, tab.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
      var start_index = chainage.findIndex(x => x > start);
      var end_index = chainage.findIndex(x => x >= end) - start_index;
    
    
      for (row of rows) {
        var color = tab.getRange('c' + row).getBackground();
            tab.getRange(row, start_index+3, 1, end_index+1).clear().setBackground(null).breakApart();
      }  
    
    }
    
    //Delete function unmerge barchart
    function deLete() {
      
      var [tab,x4,start,x1, end,x2, side,x3, item] = sheet.getRange("C5:C13").getValues().flat();
      var [tesNo,y1, rfiNo] = sheet.getRange("G15:G17").getValues().flat();
    
    
    
      var rows = get_rows(tab, side, item);
      unMerge(tab, rows, start, end);
    
    }
    
    //set delete button
    function deleteRocrd(){
     //before check save or edit and after save new record
    if(searchCell == ""){
      return
    }
    
    if(accept == true){
    //set edit
    const cellfound = regiWs.getRange("A2:A")
                        .createTextFinder(idCell)
                        .matchCase(true)
                        .matchEntireCell(true)
                        .findNext();
    if(!cellfound) return
    const rowNo = cellfound.getRowIndex();
    regiWs.deleteRow(rowNo);
    deLete();
    newRecord();
    // ss.toast("Recrod Deleted..!","Delete Id:- "+idCell);
    }
    else{
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Please tick the I Confirmed checkbox");
      return
    }
    }
```

How can this problem be solved? I printed in the log and searched for myself? But I don't know if it's worth it.

Comment: In your script, what function do you run? For example, if `deleteRocrd()` is run, an error occurs because `searchCell`, `accept`, `idCell` are not declared. So I cannot understand your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: can you try logging tab, it's possible that it is returning NULL, check if your sheetname  matches the value in C5. There could also be extra spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you run deLete() first then tab is not a sheet it is assigned a value

```
function deLete() {
  var [tab, x4, start, x1, end, x2, side, x3, item] = sheet.getRange("C5:C13").getValues().flat();//tab is assigned a value
  var [tesNo, y1, rfiNo] = sheet.getRange("G15:G17").getValues().flat();
  var rows = get_rows(tab, side, item);
  unMerge(tab, rows, start, end);//tab is not a sheet here
}

function unMerge(tab, rows, start, end) {
  Logger.log("trst " + tab);
  var chainage_row = tab.getRange("C:C").getValues().flat().indexOf('Chainage') + 1;
  var chainage = tab.getRange(chainage_row, 4, 1, tab.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  var start_index = chainage.findIndex(x => x > start);
  var end_index = chainage.findIndex(x => x >= end) - start_index;
  for (row of rows) {
    var color = tab.getRange('c' + row).getBackground();
    tab.getRange(row, start_index + 3, 1, end_index + 1).clear().setBackground(null).breakApart();
  }
}
```

Change one of the variables and rewrite the function

Globally tab is defined as:

`const tab =spreadsheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange("C5").getValue());` 
globally it's a sheet

but in the delete function tab is defined:

var [tab, x4, start, x1, end, x2, side, x3, item] = sheet.getRange("C5:C13").getValues().flat();

inside delete it's the name of the sheet

Comment: Why is tab not valued here? "C5" is the name of a tab in the workbook. But why not just add it to the variable tab here?
This function works without any problems when used to save the same data.